# The closure of a number field under the $p$-adic topology

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, local-field

We fix an inclusion $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\hookrightarrow\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$.

Given $K$ a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, can we always find $K_0$ a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that the closure of $K_0$ in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ under the $p$-adic topology is $K$?

Another question is how to determine all elements of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\cap\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Comment: As in @hunter's answer, being a little careful, yes, every finite extension of $\mathbb Q_p$ can be obtained by adjoining elements of $\overline{\mathbb Q_p}$ in fact algebraic over $\mathbb Q$. The problem in addressing your second question is that it is hard to usefully describe "a fixed inclusion of $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ into $\overline{\mathbb Q_p}$". As in some other comments, a single finite extension of $\mathbb Q$ can have significantly different behavior in its several imbeddings into $\overline{\mathbb Q_p}$... and it is hard to specify/distinguish them.

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me as if your second question is: “What is the algebraic closure of $\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb Q_p$?”

I can’t imagine how one would describe all elements of that field, but at least I can point out that for every $n\ge1$ this field has a subfield (in fact many) that is of degree $n$ over $\Bbb Q$.

Start with the polynomial $g(X)=X^n+X+p$, which has a root in $\Bbb Q_p$. For all I know, it’s $\Bbb Q$-irreducible already, but if it isn’t, I’ll jiggle it a little so it becomes $\Bbb Q$-irreducible.

Let $q$ be any other prime than $p$, and let $a_0\in\Bbb Z$ with $a_0\equiv0\pmod{p^2}$ but $a_0\equiv q-p\pmod{q^2}$, using Chinese Remainder. Also, let $a_1\in\Bbb Z$ with $a_1\equiv0\pmod p$ and $a_1\equiv-1\pmod q$.

Now let $f(X)=g(X)+a_1X+a_0=X^n+(a_1+1)X+(a_0+p)$, our jiggled polynomial. Looking through the $p$-lens, we see that $v_p(a_1+1)=0$ and $v_p(a_0+p)=1$, so Hensel still gives us a $\Bbb Q_p$-root of $f$. On the other hand, the $q$-view gives us $v_q(a_1+1)\ge1$ and $v_q(a_0+p)=1$, which is enough to bring in Eisenstein (using the prime $q$), and $\Bbb Q$-irreducibility of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your questions have answers named after famous lemmas.

For your first question: yes, this follows from Krasner's lemma. Basically any polynomial sufficiently close to the minimal polynomial for $K$ but with rational coefficients will cut out the right extension for you.

EDIT: this is not complete, see the comments.
For your second: if $\alpha \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $p$ is not ramified in the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ you can appeal to Hensel's lemma. If $p$ is ramified and the extension is Galois then $\alpha$ is not in $\mathbb{Q}_p$; otherwise I am not sure.

Comment: Thank you. For the second part, could you make it more clear?

Comment: The claim "if $\alpha \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $p$ is ramified in the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ then certainly $\alpha \notin \mathbb{Q}_p$" is wrong, and the claim "Otherwise it is not" in the previous comment by @hunter is also wrong. Let $f(x) = x^4 + 2x^3 + x^2 + 2x + 8$ and let $\alpha = 2^2 + 2^4 + 2^5 + 2^6 + 2^7 + 2^8 + 2^10 + \ldots$.

Comment: @user760870 you're quite right (I don't see how you found the root, though). I guess issue is there exists a prime above $p$ that is not ramified in this non-Galois extension even though there is another prime above $p$ that is. Thanks! Deleting the wrong comment and modifying the answer accordingly.

Comment: @user760870 So the right answer should be "the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ needs to have $\alpha$ as a simple root mod $p$"and not "the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ needs to have all simple roots mod $p$,"right? why don't you post that

Comment: The polynomial I listed does not have $\alpha$ as a simple root modulo $p$. If $\alpha$ is a simple root mod $p$ then it lies in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ but that is not necessary. The condition that a field $K$ has *some* embedding into $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is just that there exists a unramified prime $\mathfrak{p}$ with residue field $\mathbf{F}_p$.

Comment: I can tell you how @user760870 found that root of that polynomial. When you draw the Newton Polygon, you see that there are segments of width $1$ and slope $-2$, width $1$ and slope $-1$. Thus there are rational roots of valuation $2$ and $1$, respectively. You find them by Hensel or a variant of Weierstrass Preparation.